# REGEX IN DATAFRAME PANDAS

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column like that

```
COL1
PACK[5.95 $ /if game game1 + game1]
PACK[3 $ /2 products.]
```

I want create other column as following according COL1

```
pack_plus    pack
5,95          3
```

I am ok for pack_plus : `PACK\[(\d[\d.]*) $[^][]*\+[^][]*]`

but not for pack (I dont want to select raw with "+")

I have this : `PACK\[(\d[\d.]*) €[^][()]*]`

Thank you

Comment: the values are on multiple lines, how are you creating the new index? can you show a few more rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
PACK\[(\d[\d.]*)\s*\$[^][+]*]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DU8ejJ/1).

**Details**

- `PACK\[` - `PACK[` string
- `(\d[\d.]*)`  - Group 1: a digit and then zero or more digits or dots
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `[^][+]*` - zero or more chars other than `]`, `[` and `+`
- `]` - a `]` char.